# How to test and compare stored procedures in Sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have optimised a stored procedure and created as new one. i want to test the new and old one whether both are pulling same data ie. i wanted to do some automated testing.

Anyone please help on this

Answer (score 2):

**You can achieve this by using in-memory tables.**

Let's say you have a stored procedure named `getUsers` which will give you the list of all the users. The result set contains the fields: `Id`, `Name`,`Username`. Now you can save the result set returned by this stored procedure in an in-memory table, do the same for another stored procedure in an another in-memory table and then compare these two tables.

*How can I save the result set of a stored procedure?*

Here's how you do it:

```
declare @MyTable table (Id int, [Name] varchar(50), [Username] varchar(50));

insert into @MyTable
exec getUsers
```

Do the same thing for the other stored procedure, then compare the result sets returned.

Comment: But my data is huge, i dont want to do manual comparision. i want some thing is should auto compare and says the data is similar.

Comment: Well, then you can write some code to stream the data row by row and compare the results. I don't know what you exactly mean by _auto compare_, you have to write the comparison logic through a comparator (whether you compare some fields or all).

Comment: And for the huge data problem, you can use pagination if you want to do the testing on SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question,but in sqlserver has `Audit`&`Execution Plan` maybe solve auto do tasks,you can try